# Generate a realistic stock price

Tags: algorithm, simulation, genetic-algorithm, stock

I'm trying to apply a genetic algorithm to find a way that find currency arbitrage http://priceonomics.com/jobs/puzzle/. So I want for that generate a fake but realistic stock exchange rate that allow currency arbitrage like their API but with more currency (7-8) (I couldn't find any real dataset with enough frenquency to get such opportunity),

Comment: arbitrage is detected using Bellman-Ford usually, why did you chose to use GA here?

Comment: I read papers that use GA for better performance, and I want to compare the result (Time and rate) I get from bellman-ford with GA algorithm and with Simulated annealing

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion and related pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't generate fake data. You might accidentally insert some bias or pattern into your data and your algorithm might pick it up.

Instead try finding some actual data. Since you need it for testing you can use old data.

The website you mention offers you an api to get actual data. Download a few datasets and use those.

Comment: Yeah but actually I need to find an opportunity of currency arbitrage and they occur for a short amount of time like 2-3 seconds. And I cannot found any data which give me the rate of each currency each second for a given   day. Except if you know such dataset I have to generate a fake one. On the API they give a fake rate.